# hibernate multiple database configuration files

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have the database config show below file that reads from the application.properties which has information to connect to a single data base.

I want to add another similar configuration file that will allow me to connect to another database and use its session factory like the primary one I already have.

I am working on making another similar file which reads from another application properties file. However I am not sure how to wire it so that I can have multiple session factories in each of my entity classes

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Value("${db.driver}")
  private String DB_DRIVER;

  @Value("${db.password}")
  private String DB_PASSWORD;

  @Value("${db.url}")
  private String DB_URL;

  @Value("${db.username}")
  private String DB_USERNAME;

  @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
  private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

  @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
  private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

  @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
  private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

  @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
  private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

} // class DatabaseConfig
```

Usage of session factory in a generic dao. I would like another session factory that can connect to another datasource.

```
@Repository("baseDao")
@Transactional
public class BaseDaoImpl<T extends Serializable> implements BaseDao<T> {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

...
```

Comment: go ahead define a second `SessionFactory ` with a different configuration and Autowire it also in the BaseDao, check the Qualifier annotation [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/) . Also you have to think about how in runtime you are going to decide each time which factory should be used.

Comment: Hi so I have the same exact file with a different propertysource. I am confused as to how to auto wire it. I have a new entity for a table from the second schema. But when I run it is unable to find tables from the second database.