# Hibernate use transaction manager for subclass dao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am making a spring boot app with hibernate and I have a hierarchy of DAOs. 
I also have 2 transaction managers for two different databases.

I have a BaseDao, a BaseDB1Dao, and BaseDB2Dao.

The Base dao is as follows. I do not keep the @Transactional annotation with the BaseDao.

```
public interface BaseDao<T extends Serializable> {

    T create(T t);

    T read(Class<T> entityClass, long id);

    void update(T t);

}

public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T extends Serializable> implements BaseDao<T>{

    protected abstract Session getSession();

    @Override
    public T create(T t) {
        getSession().save(t);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T read(Class<T> entityClass, long id) {
        return  (T) getSession().get(entityClass, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T t) {
        getSession().update(t);
    }
}
```

The BaseDB1Dao and BaseDB2Dao's inherit and extend BaseDao with additional functions related to the schemas in addition to the basic functions. The main difference is that I specify the @transactional annotation as follows. I only post BaseDB1 because they are both almost identical

```
public interface BaseDB1Dao<T extends Serializable> extends BaseDao<T>{
    // add additional generic transaction functions here
}

@Repository("baseDB1Dao")
@Transactional("db1TransactionManager")
public class BaseDB1DaoImpl<T extends Serializable> extends BaseDaoImpl<T> implements BaseDB1Dao<T> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("db1SessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, the **read queries work fine** and pull from respective DBs. But **transctional queries like create do not work and fail with error**

```
Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

This is because the One of the sub dao of BaseDB1Da0, UserDao, just calls the basic create function defined in BaseDao.

One solution is I add @Transactional to BaseDaoImpl as follows

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T extends Serializable> implements BaseDao<T>{

    protected abstract Session getSession();
....
```

However that results in **another** error for **both** reads and writes. This happens because the user create function is inherited from the BaseDao and it goes there when the create function is called

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: db1TransactionManager,db2TransactionManager
```

**So the overall question is:** Is there a way to use the tranactionManager of the child class for a function in the parent class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a dedicated bean with name transactionManager handling both other transaction managers (db1TransactionManager, db2TransactionManager). Spring supports this out of the box simply by defining a custom bean with name transactionManager of tpye ChainedTransactionManager. The detailed declaration depends on your setup, so it is not guaranteed that the following works.

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager, PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager)
        throws Exception {
    return new ChainedTransactionManager(db1TransactionManager,
           db2TransactionManager);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The way my project is setup is that I have two separate configuration files both having the structure as seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925768/hibernate-multiple-database-configuration-files.

How would I calll this function so it takes both the transaction managers?

Comment: The HibernateTransactionManager is a PlatformTransactionManager so you define one of them for each datasource and than pass it to this method. Just ensure that the method name of the two other transaction managers have a different name. (method name is the bean name)

Comment: Thanks this worked. I just added this to my main databse config file and merged both my database configuration files as well.